# Invalid maximum heap size: The specified size exceeds the maximum representable size

Tags: android

I get this error when I build my project in android studio preview beta 4.
the error is:

> Error:Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine.
>   Error:Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit.
>   Error:Invalid maximum heap size: -Xmx4g
>   Error:The specified size exceeds the maximum representable size.
>   Error:Execution failed for task ':Q-municate_app:transformClassesWithDexForDevDebug'.
>   com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException

I use : https://quickblox.com/developers/Sample-webrtc-android#Sources project to build chat video app.

Comment: Well, where are you assigning a 4g heap size?

Comment: yes it is 4g in my project

Comment: Well, according to the error, you should try changing it. Why have you set it so large?

Comment: Are you using a 64 bit Java installation?

Comment: It is previously set by the company of source code  . I will set it 1g and try to build the project .

Comment: No I use 32 bit java installation .

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/154075/discussion-between-m-alkenani-and-cricket-007).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I use 32 bit java installation

32 bit applications can't use 4g of RAM. Hence `size exceeds the maximum representable size`

You either need to use a smaller heap, or use 64 bit Java